# pandas DataFrame: replace nan values with average of a certain group

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I've got a pandas DataFrame filled with real numbers and categories, but there is a few nan values in it.

How can I replace the nans with mean or median of grouped categories?

```
      A         B      
0  model 2    0.979728 
1  model 1    0.912674 
2  model 2    0.540679 
3  model 1    2.027325 
4  model 2        NaN  
5  model 1        NaN  
6  model 3   -0.612343 
7  model 1   1.033826  
8  model 1   1.025011  
9  model 2   -0.795876
```

in this case i would like to substitute two  nan with their relative mean or median.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby + transform + fillna`:

```
>>> df['B'] = df.B.fillna(df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('mean'))                                                                                                                                                          
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

        A         B
0 model 2  0.979728
1 model 1  0.912674
2 model 2  0.540679
3 model 1  2.027325
4 model 2  0.241510
5 model 1  1.249709
6 model 3 -0.612343
7 model 1  1.033826
8 model 1  1.025011
9 model 2 -0.795876
```

Comment: very good thx but in this way i have to impute manually the mean, but my dataset is very big so the effort in this way will be very high. Is it possible to use a groupby like this? group_data_median = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].median()  # sum function